# How to take snapshot of app running on simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uikit

I used this code to take the snapshot of my app running on simulator, the quality of the snap is not good, Any idea?

```
-(IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(Self.View.bounds.size,Self.View.opaque,10.0f);
    [Self.View.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    /* Render the screen shot at custom resolution */
    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,500);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size,BrochureSave.opaque,10.0f);
    [screenshot drawInRect:cropRect];
    UIImage * customScreenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();      

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    /* Save to the photo album */
    // UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(customScreenShot , nil, nil, nil);

    [self.library saveImage:customScreenShot toAlbum:@"Cemara roll" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Big error: %@",[error description]);
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Image Save Cemara roll" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Don't scale it, keep it the same size

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `10.0f` to `0.0f` in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`:

here:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(Self.View.bounds.size,Self.View.opaque,0.0f);
```

Comment: I try it but image resolution is low?

Comment: I updated the answer (change is only on the first one)

Comment: I change is only on the first one,but image resolution is low?

Comment: Then what about if you change in both places?

Comment: change in both places,but image resolution is low?

Comment: The quality of the snapshot will be the same pixel resolution as the device you're running... please post the screenshot of the current screen and after the snapshot.

Comment: You can edit your question and add it there so everyone will try to help

Comment: Btw, try `1.0f` instead of `0.0f`